# UITabBarController Weirdness ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, selectedindex

If I normally load up a `UITabBarController` and switch between views, it calls the `viewWillAppear` of each view controller.
But it is not so.

***I want to switch to another tab as soon as another tab is touched.***

If I specify a tab to load up - for example `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0]` in the `viewWillAppear` of one of the tabs (say tab 4)... It goes immediately back to tab 0.

But after that....  it does not call the `viewWillAppear` on any of the tabs when I switch between them. 
For example, if I again go to tab 4, it does not come back to tab 0. I expect it to by a never ending cycle as I expect tab 0 to load up as soon as tab 4 is touch.

But it runs **JUST ONCE** !!

Why ??

---

***Note:** Question has been edited.*

Comment: This question does not need any code. I would be happy to post code but explaining with a code will make the question TOO long.  The question is straight forward.

Comment: OK. So where do you call `setSelectedItem`? In some static method (e.g. `applicationDidFinichLaunching`) or somwhere else?

Comment: Actually you brought up a good point. Let me edit the question to my exact scenario

Comment: Have you checked the `viewDidDisappear:` methods for each view?  Though I doubt it's the case, the views may not know they have disappeared and thus can't appear again.  If nothing else, it could be worth checking

Comment: I can reproduce only halp of this. I've set up two tabs and if I click  on the second I call `setSelectedIndex:0` and it shwitches to 0 calling `viewWillAppear` in it. But it runs just once... Are you sure that `viewWillAppear` on your '0' tab is not called?

Comment: @Kashiv: Yes, ofcourse. That is why I am posting the question here. I tried NSLogging at various places, and I still have the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution. It works **every time** you click on your tab and it **calls viewWillAppear** on both tabs.

You can do this in your `AppDelegate` (or somwhere else in UITabBarController's delegate):

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

---

Sample code:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if([self.tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController] == 1) {
        [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach will lead to the situations when **viewWillAppear** will be called twice (native by user interaction and sec on by this code). If there is no critical code inside **viewWillAppear** than no problem.

Comment: You can always create a property indicating that the critical code should be executed or not

Answer (score 0):

setting the selectedIndex won't change the selectedViewController. You will have to change selectedViewController itself. Look at [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more details.

Comment: I change my selected tabs with `setSelectedIndex` and it works, so it's not that...

Comment: setting setSelectedIndex just changes the selected tab, but it doesn't handle it like a touch on the specified item. You will **need** to set selectedViewController.

Comment: No, he doesn't. `setSelectedIndex != setSelectedTab`. It automatically sets `selectedViewControler`.

Comment: @Legolas I think what @yinkou is right. Try to do something like this: `[[self tabBarController] setSelectedViewController:[[[self tabBarController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]]`

Comment: Using `-selectedIndex:` will have no effect if the More nav controller is in use and the indexed tab effectively lives within it. In those cases, `-selectedViewController:` is the way to do it, per the docs.